# Who stole my gold badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I was looking at my questions on my profile and found [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/is-the-pit-in-dark-knight-rises-a-representation-of-ras-al-ghuls-lazarus-pit) had 10K views. I looked up the 
description of [famous question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) mine seems to fit the bill.

Is there any latency in awarding of those gold badges?

Edit: i might have jumped the gun when i looked at the questions from my profile it was showing this view. i think it rounds it to next 1000th value for views?

[image]

Comment: Yah, a lot of stuff gets rounded - views, reputation score etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only see **9555**:

[image]

---

I think I see your confusion.  When you go to the Questions page it'll show a number **rounded up** from the actual count:

[image]

Comment: i updated my question.

Comment: You can also hover over "10k views" and you will get the number of views in a tooltip. See, for example, [this meta.SO post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158126/expand-tooltip-hover-area-for-questions-with-1-000-views).